# Strange behavior in IE when combining click handler with CSS sibling selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I am trying to design a menu that is triggered by clicking a button. When the user clicks the button, a click handler runs which adds a class to the button, and a CSS rule using an sibling selector makes the menu visible. It works fine in all the browsers I tested except IE 7 and 8.

In IE 7 and 8, I am experiencing these problems:

1. Clicking the button toggles the class but the menu doesn't appear or disappear until I move the mouse around a little bit.
2. The menu doesn't work at all unless I have a CSS :hover declaration for children of the menu. It doesn't matter what I put in the declaration, or if I put anything at all, but the menu does not show up without it.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and what I can do about it? I was thinking of adding a separate class to the menu but I am wondering if there is a simpler fix or workaround. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>IE selector test</title>
<style type="text/css">
button {
  border: outset 1px #eeeeee;
}
button.active {
  border-style: inset;
}
.menu {
  display: none;
  border: solid 1px #888888;
}
button.active ~ .menu {
  display: block;
}
.menu > :hover {
  /* For some reason, the menu doesn't work at all without this declaration */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="menuButton">Menu</button>
<div class="menu">
  <div>option</div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("menuButton").onclick = function() {
  if (this.className) {
    this.className = "";
  } else {
    this.className = "active";
  }
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also test it at http://jsfiddle.net/QKqpn/.

Comment: `~` is not the adjacent sibling selector; it's the general sibling selector. The adjacent sibling selector is represented by `+`.

Comment: @BoltClock, you are right. I corrected my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around it by forcing page redraw:

```
document.body.className = document.body.className;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/uGW4M/

BTW, in your case you can use `+` (one immediate sibling) combinator instead of more common `~` (all subsequent siblings):

```
button.active + .menu {/* ... */}
```

Comment: The className thing worked. The + didn't. Thank you. I will accept your answer if I don't somehow get a better answer in the next few days.

Comment: `+` works here: http://jsfiddle.net/E7RaA/ (tested in IE9 in both IE7 and IE8 modes).

Comment: I tried your fiddle and it seems like the + has nothing to do with whether it works. It only works with the + because of your document.body.className line. If I take that out, it doesn't work. I am using ~ instead of + because I am not quite sure of the final design of my menu.

Comment: Part of my answer related to `+` has nothing to do with fixing your problem. It's just _By The Way_ (BTW) note. If you need only immediate sibling, it makes sense to not force browser to search for all siblings.